# Javascript: Using a timestamp as a temporary ID # VS Using a counter as a temporary ID #

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and we need a unique temporary number to identify a set of data.  I want to use the timestamp, my coworker wants to use a counter variable.

Which approach is better?  My thought is less overhead as we just get the timestamp when the user clicks the add button when they want to add the set of data vs having to keep track of a counter.

Keep in mind, I'm new to web development and I am biased towards my own idea.

Comment: I'm not seeing the benefit of using a timestamp over a counter... edit: I see what you mean: that every time you create a timestamp, you're sure it's unique... I would still go with the counter, because, if needed, you would also be able to cycle through the elements.

Comment: Explain to us what you're trying to accomplish instead of a 'which is better' simply because what you're asking is do we like blue paint or green paint as though we are artists. So really you have to decide what color the water and sky are in this 'land scape' and apply the correct color to the correct situation.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether or not there is another thread running that can possibly pull the same exact timestamp. but if you're absolutely positive that you wont run in to this issue, use the timestamp, and you don't need to keep track of a counter.

Comment: I'm not sure about the thread issue.  This code is still new to me.  Counter may be safer.  I just thought the timestamp was very elegant due to the 100% uniqueness factor.  I don't have time to go through and find out if that's the case either.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [**Guid**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) instead? That would be an unique identifier based on time, among other variables, that won't repeat itself either; and it's safer against duplicates in a multi-threaded environment than using `DateTime.Now.Ticks`